# Get data from active child route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My routes with data.

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'customer', component:  CustomerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { title: 'Customer' }, children: [
        { path: 'new', component:  CreateCustomerComponent, data: { title: 'New customer' }, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
    ]}
];
```

Get data from active route in component:

```
this.activeComponent = this.route.snapshot.data.title;
if ( this.route.snapshot.firstChild) {
  this.activeComponent = this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data.title;
}
```

I can't get that child's data title.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622526/11719787

Comment: Yes I tried but data is just empty

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the moment of getting snapshot, the child is not rendered yet. As a result, you don't have child's data. 
You may use `@ViewChild` and then get child's data or create service to communicate. You may also subscribe to route's changes ([ActivatedRoute#data](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data))