# How can I get the Route object in Angular from a url string?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm trying to get the Route object from passing a url.

```
interface Route {
    path?: string;
    pathMatch?: string;
    matcher?: UrlMatcher;
    component?: Type<any>;
    redirectTo?: string;
    outlet?: string;
    canActivate?: any[];
    canActivateChild?: any[];
    canDeactivate?: any[];
    canLoad?: any[];
    data?: Data;
    resolve?: ResolveData;
    children?: Routes;
    loadChildren?: LoadChildren;
    runGuardsAndResolvers?: RunGuardsAndResolvers;
}
```

In my navigation component I wish to access the Route information by passing a URL, as the route Object's data property contains my Access roles. I know that I can extract this Access role information to a map and the share the key between my Routes object and my Navigation object. But I was hoping to find some kind of why to traverse the Routes object and extract my access information from there.

This is what my Navigation object looks like:

```
{ path: '/maintenance/countries', name: 'Countries' }
```

So the path in this is passed to a routerLink in my Template. Thus what I'm looking for is a way to use that same path to get to the data as set up in the Routes object for that path. I can't just do a standard filter on the Routes object due to the fact that there are nested paths, so I suspect I need some way to use Angular's UrlMatcher.

Lastly, a fictitious example of what I was looking for:

```
const foundRoute: Route = this.router.findRoute('/maintenance/countries');
const hasAccess = this.authService.hasAccess(foundRoute.data.roles());
```

Comment: Kindly have a glance on this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877410/angular-6-get-current-route-and-its-data

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.router` has a field `config` containig all configured routes. So you could do:

```
const foundRoute: Route = this.router.config.filter(route => route.path === '/maintenance/countries')[0];
```

However, this only works for "simple" routes (without any matchers like `*`). For others you have to think about a slightly more advanced filter.